# Unity: The type name or alias could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name

Tags: unity-container

I have the following classes / interfaces in Web API project

```
namespace API.Services
{
    public class APIService : IAPIService
    {
        public APIService() { }
    }
}

namespace API.Services
{
    public interface IAPIService
    {
    }
}
```

I am trying to resolve via a Unity configuration file as below:

```
<Unity>

    <typeAliases>

      <typeAlias alias="singleton" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity"/>

      <typeAlias alias="IAPIService" type="API.Services.IAPIService, API.Services"/>  

    </typeAliases>

    <containers>
      <container>
        <types>

          <type
            type="IAPIService"
            mapTo="API.Services.APIService, API.Services"
                >
          </type>

        </types>


      </container>
    </containers>
  </Unity>
```

I am then in app start reading from config file and attempting to configure the section

```
UnityConfigurationSection section = 
(UnityConfigurationSection)config.GetSection("Unity");

section.Configure(container); << error here
```

At which point I get the error System.InvalidOperationException: 'The type name or alias IAPIService could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So you are mixing "use alias" and "don't use alias".  Personally, I would never do this.

Option 1: (no aliases)

You need to put the assembly name in with the interface as well.

Generic Example below.  This would be if both the interface and the concrete object were in the same assembly "MyCompany.Apps", aka "MyCompany.Apps.dll"

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
<container>


<register type="MyCompany.Apps.MyInterfaceObject, MyCompany.Apps" mapTo="MyCompany.Apps.MyConcreteObject, MyCompany.Apps" />



</container>
</unity>
```

Option 2: (use alias consistently)

Below shows the interface and concrete-object in the same assembly "MyCompany.MyTechnology.MyApplications", aka, "MyCompany.MyTechnology.MyApplications.dll"

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">

  <typeAliases>

    <typeAlias alias="IMyInterfaceObjectAlias"  type="MyCompany.MyTechnology.MyApplications.Interfaces.IMyInterfaceObject, MyCompany.MyTechnology.MyApplications" />
    <typeAlias alias="MyConcreteObjectAlias"  type="MyCompany.MyTechnology.MyApplications.MyConcreteObject, MyCompany.MyTechnology.MyApplications" />

  </typeAliases>

  <containers>

    <container>

      <register type="IMyInterfaceObjectAlias" mapTo="MyConcreteObjectAlias"/>

    </container>

  </containers>
</unity>
```

PS

using "singleton" (a keyword) as the name of an alias....isn't a great idea IMHO.  While technically it might work, the time wasted debugging keyword (and also ambiguously named) things isn't worth it.

Note how I put "Alias" at the end of my named Alias to avoid ambiguity.

Just offering a friendly tip.